# Finding mode of Array in O(n)

Tags: java, algorithm, list, collections, time-complexity

I thought I got this right, to find the mode in O(n). But when timing, it seems to take much closer to O(n*log(n)):

```
public int mode(List<Integer> numList) {
    //Holds frequencies
    int[] frequencies = new int[Collections.max(numList)+1];

    for(int i=0; i<numList.size(); i++) {
        frequencies[numList.get(i)]+=1;
    }

    //Convert to List
    List<Integer> freqArray = IntStream.of(frequencies).boxed().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

    int maxFreq = Collections.max(freqArray);
    int mode = freqArray.indexOf(maxFreq);

    return mode;
}
```

Where am I going wrong? Thanks

Comment: What you are doing is like counting sort. It would not yield the output for every input. `[1,2147483647]` or `[-4,-5,-6]`

Comment: You are allocating too much memory for lists that are not evenly distributed. Better use a HashMap to calculate in O(n) time.

Comment: @vivek_23 He is asking for help with homework. He posted this question earlier and it got downvoted into oblivion. Then he deleted it. His professor specifically asked for O(n*log(n)). I told him how to do O(n) earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost right as most of the operations take up to O(n) time, except maybe for streams. They can take more time than O(n) even when traversing through `Iterable` of length n. More [here](https://jaxenter.com/java-performance-tutorial-how-fast-are-the-java-8-streams-118830.html).

Answer (score 0):

Like @Andronicus specified, you can get rid of streams and use pure Arrays not even lists. But again, with your approach your time complexity isn't `O(n)`, it is `O(m)`, where `m` is the maximum element in your array. Also like mentioned in the comments, your approach won't work for negative values. In such cases `HashMap` is your best bet and most of the time guarantees `O(1)` inserts/fetches for calculating hashes for simple types like integers.